# Replacements for eval function with better one

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

I want to replace 'eval' in the below example with better function. Upon research it has come to my understanding that using this is not a good idea.

```
class_name = '{}'.format(SIP.supported_classes_dictionary[msg_type])
print 'Testing {}'.format(eval(class_name).supported_sip_services[msg_type])
variable_array = eval(class_name).fields_desc[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you're trying to achieve it is probably not the worst choice, as long as the classes dictionary is no (untrusted) user input.

For improving the code, when you control the dictionary as well, consider putting the classes inside the dictionary instead of the class names. This would solve the problem more elegant.

Something like

```
class A:
    pass
class B:
    pass
myclasses = [A, B]
for cls in myclasses:
    print cls.__name__
```

is possible and avoids converting between strings and python objects/classes.

Comment: Minor quibble: `os` and `sys` aren't classes, they are modules. It would work with classes too, of course.

Comment: Opps, indeed. Had something else in mind. I change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the classes themselves, rather than their names, as the values in your dictionary. Then you will be able to do

```
chosen_class = SIP.supported_classes_dictionary[msg_type]
print 'Testing {}'.format(chosen_class.supported_sip_services[msg_type])
variable_arry = chosen_class.fields_desc[2:]
```

On the last two lines I have replaced your `eval(class_name)` with just `chosen_class`. This is made possible by two things:

1. Changing the variable name on the first line from `class_name` to `chosen_class` (this is just a cosmetic detail)
2. Populanting `SIP.supported_classes_dictionary` with classes rather than strings. As you haven't shown how you do this in your code sample, I can't show you the exact change you have to make, but it might be something along the lines of changing `d[some_message_type] = 'SomeClass'` to `d[some_message_type] = SomeClass` i.e., remove the quotes around your class name, when you stick it into the dictionary.